# <link > is Not connecting to CSS from inside JSP

Tags: css, jsp, servlets

my index.jsp and main.css are both under same directory and none of them are under WEB-INF.
Here is my jsp code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />     
    </head>
    <body>
```

And also my css.

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
h1{
    color: #008060;   
}
textarea{
    font-size: 16px;  
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
input[type="submit"]{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;   
}
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    border-collapse: collapse;   
}
th , td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
.answer{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px 10px;
}
@media only screen  and (max-width: 800px){
    .main{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

}
```

When i put my css code inside style tag Code it perfectly works.
but when i put it in main.css and linking it back it doesn't work completely.
only color and font are working. seems like its linked to another main.css. but when i look its only one and I am using netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You should change link from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
```

to

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: if you dont use JSTL please use this <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: that even didn't work at first. but as soon as i put my file in style folder and used this it worked. <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />.

Comment: is there any reason?

Comment: request.getContextPath() will get relative path for you, link to css will like this http://localhost:8080/yourapp/style/main.css